# Proving something is a lattice .

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders

Hi i was wondering if anyone could help me show the following

$f\le^{*}g \iff \exists k\forall m\ge k(f(m)\le g(m)$ Show that $\le^{*}$ is a lattice.

My definition of a lattice is the following let $\le$ be a partial ordering on $X$ and that $\sup\{x,y\}$ and $\inf\{x,y\}$ exist in $X$ $\forall x,y\in X$ then $\le$ is a lattice.?

I'm unsure where to start this problem, i know that i need to show that the $\inf\{x,y\}$ and $\sup\{x,y\}$ exists but how would i do that?

Comment: What are $f$ and $g$?

Comment: Erm good question it doesn't specify so I'm assuming there real functions

Comment: The relation $\le^*$ is not even a partial order, so it cannot define a lattice. The problem is anti-symmetry. Let $f(x)=x$, and let $g(x)=x$ for $x\ge 2$ and $g(x)=0$ for $x<2$. Then $f\le^* g$ and $g\le^* f$, but $f\neq g$.

Comment: Does k have to be positive?

Comment: @WilliamElliot  I don't think so it doesn't give any more information about the question

Answer (score 0):

As was pointed out, <=* is not a porder.
It is only a preorder.  To rescue the problem for
functions f:R -> R a porder instead of a preorder is needed.

Define f eventually = g, f == g as
some k in R with for all x >= k, f(x) = g(x)
Show == is an equivalent relation.

To show the equivalent classes are a lattice
using f eventually <= g, f <=* g when
some k in R with for all x >= k, f(x) <= g(x).

Define [f] <<= [g] when f <=* g.
Show that <<= is well defined.
That is, if f ~ h, g ~ k, f <=* g, then h <=* k.
Continue to show <<= is a partial order.
Finally show [max(f,g)] = sup([f],[g]) and define inf.

Whence this curve ball problem?
Did you include all the details?

Comment: It was a problem my lecturer gave me to help practice showing things are lattices & i included all the details he gave